# Why is the interior of a connected set not connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I refer to the answer in the following link as the source of my question.

[In a metric space X, if A is connected, is its interior connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089859/in-a-metric-space-x-if-a-is-connected-is-its-interior-connected?newreg=df7ee0c58229441aa1a0c85fa0652d7c)

While I understand the counterexample given, I actually thought that the interior of a connected set is connected. My proof is as follows:

Since $A$ is a connected set, suppose we take any two-valued function $f$ on $A$. Then, for any $a \in A$, $f(a)=c$ for some constant $c$. Since $A^{\circ} \subset A$, the restriction of $f$ on $A^{\circ} $ is also constant, that is, $f|_{A^{\circ}}=c$ and hence the interior of a connected set is connected.

Does the two-valued function argument only work on $\mathbb{R}$  or am I missing something fundamental? Thank you.

Comment: May be there are two-valued continuous functions defined on $A^\circ$ that cannot be gotten by restricting a two-valued continuous function on all of $A$?

Comment: I agree with @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex, then $A^\circ$ is convex. So its true for convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, its true for $\mathbb{R}$, since $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is convex iff its connected.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Should it not be the other way around since we are assuming $A$ is connected and not $A^{\circ}$? I mean should it not be that I cannot restrict $f$ on $A^{\circ}$ because $f$ might lose its continuity?

Comment: Generally if you've written a proof of a false statement, it's good practice to try and "run" your proof on a counterexample showing the statement is false. In this case, hopefully you agree that the interior of the two discs is not connected? So you can define a function which is $0$ on the interior of the left disc but $1$ on the interior of the right disc. You're claiming you've proved this isn't possible. Can you see why your proof doesn't actually show that's impossible?

Comment: Nope. You want to prove that $A^\circ$ is connected. To apply the theorem with two-valued functions you need to consider **all** the two-valued continuous functions defined on $A^\circ$. In your argument you only consider those two-valued functions that are gotten by restricting a two-valued function continuous on all of $A$.

Comment: And the process of restriction always preserves continuity (assuming the usual subspace topology). The trouble begins when you want to extend a function from a smaller domain to a bigger one while preserving continuity.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think I see your point. If I restrict the function onto the interior of the left disc (or the right disc respectively), then I will get a constant function but the interior of the two tangent discs is not connected. So in sum of all the comments here, I need to start with the connectedness of $A^{\circ}$ and then work upwards to the connectedness of $A$ to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to prove the interior was always connected, the argument would have to go "suppose the interior is disconnected. .... therefore $A$ is disconnected, which is absurd". So if you're arguing via functions, the argument would have to go "let $f$ be a two-valued continuous surjection on the interior. ... Therefore $g$ is a two-valued continuous surjection on $A$, which is absurd". Your argument is "let $f$ be a two-valued function on $A$. ... Therefore $g$ is a two-valued constant function on the interior." This just proves some functions on the interior are constant - not all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that argument was correct, it prove not only $\mathring A$ is connected but, in fact, that every *subset* of $A$ is connected.

The problem lies in the implicit assumption that every continuous function $f\colon\mathring A\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ is the restriction to $\mathring A$ of some continuous function from $A$ into $\{0,1\}$. This is false.

Comment: Could you please clarify on the second part of your answer in light of the this link? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826827/topology-show-restriction-of-continuous-function-is-continuous-and-restriction . I am wondering if it is a matter of continuity not holding on the restricted function or if it is that the set in the metric space going from closed to open.

Comment: I don't see what my answer has to do with the content of that link. That link has to do with the connection between $f$ and $f|_A$. But the problem with your approach is that you seem to think (wrongly) that every continuous function from $\mathring A$ into $\{0,1\}$ is of the form $f|_{\mathring A}$, for some continuous function $f\colon A\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much!